# Vuetify Get access of valid value of <v-text-field>

Tags: validation, input, return-value

I am trying to bulid simple textinput validation. if validation fails, confirm button is disabled. But I have no idea how can I get value of that validation is true/false to put it into button.

```
<v-text-field
  v-model="inputValue"
  :rules="inputValidation"
  :type="inputData.type"
  :value="inputValue"
  :placeholder="inputData.placeholder"
  :readonly="inputData.readonly"
  @input="valueUpdate"
/>
```

validation method

```
computed: {
    inputValidation() {
      const required = (v) => !!v || 'This field is required';
      const number = (v) => (v.length === 0 || /^[0-9]+$/.test(v)) || 'Must be a number';
      if (this.inputData.type === 'text') {
        return this.inputData.required ? [required] : [true];
      }
      if (this.inputData.type === 'number') {
        return this.inputData.required ? [required, number] : [number];
      }
      if (this.inputData.type === 'email') {
        return [
          (v) => !!v || 'E-mail is required',
          (v) => /.+@.+/.test(v) || 'E-mail must be valid',
        ];
      }
      return [true];
    },
  },
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question could be improved: 1. Please add tags about the framework and language you are using (e.g. vue). 2. Please fix the grammar of the first sentence. 3. Try to reduce you code/problem to the minimum to make it easier to understand and to make the answers helpful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your inputs in form. The form has value true or false. If you have some of the inputs inside your form invalid, the value is false.

Also check example, how do rules work.

Template:

```
  <v-form
    v-model="isFormValid"
    :lazy-validation="false"
    @submit.prevent="save"
    :id="formId"
  >
    <v-text-field
      v-model="inputValue"
      :rules="rules.input"
      :type="inputData.type"
      :value="inputValue"
      :placeholder="inputData.placeholder"
      :readonly="inputData.readonly"
      @input="valueUpdate"
    />

    <v-btn :form="formId" :disabled="!isFormValid" type="submit"> submit</v-btn>
  </v-form>
```

Script:

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    isFormValid: false,
    rules: {
      input: [v => !!v || "Required"]
    }
  })
};
```